# How to intercept the agent-send option in HAproxy?

Tags: linux, haproxy

I have follwed [this article](https://icicimov.github.io/blog/server/HAProxy-dynamically-adjust-server-weight-using-external-agent/) to set up HAproxy as a load balancer for a couple servers on different ports. I want to pass an argument to the `haproxy-agent-check` script in order to have some different logic based on the port. I can send the parameter using the `agent-send` directive in the [haproxy documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#5.2-agent-send).

The question is how can I intercept the `agent-send` argument in my script and how can I test it with `telnet` or `netstat` or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the data using your programming language's TCP socket commands, then decode it using the format it was written in (i.e. UTF-8).

Comment: updated to be posed in the form of a statement with no equivocation